# Netlogo and GIS Extension: Working on some computers and not others

Tags: gis, netlogo, projection, agent-based-modeling

We are currently working on an ABM using GIS in Netlogo. We are trying to use multiple computers to run simulations. On two of the computers, the model runs perfectly, but on the third, the GIS data will load in and then will not display.  After multiple tests, we have seen that the world envelope for one of our data sets is different than the other three. Does anyone know how to rectify this problem? We have tried transforming the data and checking to be sure we have the same data files on all three computers, but it does not seem to help our problem.

Comment: could you show what code you are using to set the envelope in NetLogo?

Comment: could it also be a problem reagrding language settings on the PCs operating systems (like decimal symbol or digit grouping symbol)?

Comment: Tyr's guess seems plausible. I feel like that has come up before.

Comment: We got it figured out today. The working instances had been open for so long, they were using old .shp and .prj files with correct functionality. Once we reverted these files to previous versions, the model ran perfectly. Thanks everyone.